# Problem with the Ubuntu-Windows double boot

Tags: dual-boot

I did not know how to install Ubuntu, so I asked a computer partner. He told me that I would do a double boot with Ubuntu and Windows 10. The problem is that when I turn on my computer it does not allow me to select the operating system I want, it only allows Ubuntu and with respect to Windows I can only select "Windows Recovery Enviroment"

What would happen if I select that option?

Ubuntu is deleted?

I'm very new in computing.

Sorry for the lousy English

Comment: May be best to see details, you can run from your Ubuntu live installer or any working install, use ppa version not older Boot-Repair ISO:
Post the link to the Create BootInfo summary report. Is part of Boot-Repair:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info and:
https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/

Answer (score 0):

Windows Recovery Environment should work just fine. It certainly will not wipe out your Ubuntu install. Select Windows Recovery Environment and press "enter." You will be fine.

Comment: Ignore my answer. It was late. I don't think going into Recovery Mode will break anything, but I don't think it will solve your problem.